What is this movie with the guy that is possessed?
I'm relying on memory from nearly 10 years ago. Here is as much as I can remember. The movie is about someone that's in their 20's and the man has dark hair.
In the movie he climbs in a tree to see this girl. He is somewhere in the movie and a native american indian is playing drums and looks at him and it has a huge demonic vibe to it. He and this girl are naked at one point and they draw their blood together. The girl had blonde hair. 
I think the movie is about satanism or possession. There is a short clip in the movie where some women runs out of a door and into the one next door but she is naked and you only see her from behind. The clip lasts like two seconds.
Again, from what I remember, this movie is pretty demonic. I'm not even sure if it was horror, it was just messed up. It was made before 2006 but after 1980.
